# Synchronise Laravel Eloquent instances

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

A big problem we are running into in our web application is that instances are often not synchronised. That is, imagine that we have a post with replies.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Reply');
    }
}

class Reply extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }
}
```

If I know get all replies using `$post->replies`, I can retrieve the post for each reply `$r` by using `$r->post` again. This does not perform a new query, because obviously its value is filled in when loading all the replies. What I did notice however is that each instance of `$r->post` is a different instance of `Post` than the original.

This is where the problems start, because in our (arguably a lot more complex) application we often call methods on a reply, and when we then move on in our application using our original post, it has not yet been updated according to the changes the replies may have made.

Personally, I would very much like the guarantee that these instances are equal. To be more precise, every time I retrieve an object using e.g. `Post::find($id)` I would like the same instance assuming `$id` is equal. Is there a way to force this behaviour? I considered using the cache in some way, but it would require a lot of caching, and I am not sure how to make sure that the Laravel code that deals with these relations could be influenced to pick up the instance from the cache either.

Comment: I wish I had more of your application so I could get a deeper understanding of what is happening here.. It sounds like users on the site create a reply which modifies the Post, but then the next user that attempts to load that post is getting the old Post? What do you mean "when we move on in our application using our original post"? The reply is happening in the middle of an execution where you've already loaded the post?

Comment: You definitely need to post some code that showcases what you've explained, because the explanation on its own is too convoluted.

Comment: this isn't a full answer but you're talking about the difference between instantiating VS addressing. You need to singleton your $posts somehow. This isn't very "eloquent" but it could look like: 

`$posts[$id]['replies'][$replyId]->cool_reply_method()`

The difference between is that an addressed object PERSISTS in the parent array that can later be addressed and you'll be getting the same object instance. I'd be curious what the eloquent way of handling this would be.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation when running acceptance tests.

Here is the workaround I have for the moment, until I can figure out why in some environments the PDO instance seems to be locked.

Duplicate your default connection in `config/database.php`:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],

'mysql_alt' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
]
```

Now, when needed you can proceed as follow:

```
Model::on('mysql_alt')->find($id)
```